# How to save cuda memory with torch in this case?

Tags: memory-management, out-of-memory, pytorch

Just as the code below, I am trying to get the mean of 47 repeated outputs of the model. But it is always out of memory. If I remove the `z_proto_class_list.append(z_proto_class)`, then it is fine. I guess it is because the memory is freed if I don't append the tensor. I am always trying to generate the 47 output at once but it is obviously more memory consuming than my current choice. Is there a method to solve my current issue? Thank you.

```
        z_proto_class_list = []
        for support_input_ids, support_input_mask, support_segment_ids in dataloader:
            s_z, s_pooled_output = model(support_input_ids, support_input_mask, support_segment_ids, output_all_encoded_layers=False)
            sz_dim = s_z.size(-1)
            index = torch.LongTensor(support_idx_list).unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(2).expand(len(support_idx_list),1,sz_dim).cuda()
            z_proto_raw = torch.gather(s_z,1,index)
            z_proto_class = z_proto_raw.view(1,n_support, sz_dim).mean(1)
            z_proto_class_list.append(z_proto_class)
            torch.cuda.empty_cache()
        z_proto = torch.cat(z_proto_class_list, 0)
```

Comment: instead of `cat` and then `mean` - just save the *sum* and divide it by the number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `z_proto_class_list.append(z_proto_class)` stored the whole computational graph so the memory won't be freed automatically. I use `z_proto_class_list.append(z_proto_class.detach())` and solved this issue. But the problem is that this doesn't fit my original implementation since I wish to update the parameter of the models given the centroid of the class instances.